# c++ initializing multiset iterator to NULL

Tags: c++, null, iterator, initialization

the issue is I want to initialize a **multiset iterator** to some value, to be able to check later if there was some successful assignment to my iterator or not. Now without this initialization in some cycle of my program I get there some trash and all crashes.
In pseudocode I'd think about it like that:

```
multiset<whateverclassA,whateverclassB>::const_iterator init_me = NULL;
...//if succesfull, something is assigned to init_me iterator
if (init_me != NULL)
//do something
```

however it is not a usual pointer, so simple NULL doesn't suffice probably. 
Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`std::multiset::end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/end). This is also the value that will be returned by algorithms like [`std::multiset::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/find) if the value could not be found:

```
multiset<whateverclassA,whateverclassB>::const_iterator 
    init_me = your_multiset.end();

/* ... */

if (init_me != your_multiset.end())
    //do something
```

Comment: but this points out to the one after last element, so actually random value, isn't it? then if I check it in if condition, can be another random value there ..

Comment: @eReM: You obviously check `init_me != ctn.end()` instead of `init_me != NULL` before dereferencing the iterator.

Comment: ok thanks, I didn't know that there is some steady value in case of using **end()**, I thought it may change continuously.

Comment: @eReM: `insert`, `emplace` `erase` and `clear` are the only things which change your set\*. `insert` and `emplace` won't invalidate any iterator or reference, `erase` will invalidate the iterator and references to the element which has been erased, and `clear` will invalidate all iterators but not the past-the-end iterator which are equal to `end()`. So you can use `end()` without any problems. (\* there's also `swap`, but I don't think you're going to use it)

Answer (score 4):

The variable `init_me` is an object instance, and `NULL` is a pointer. A non-pointer instance can not be compared to a pointer.

What you should to is set `init_me` to another iterator that means "no iterator", like `end`, and compare against that.

Answer (score 3):

If the multiset in question always exists and is determined at the time you declare `init_me` (i.e. there is only one possible multiset that the iterator can point into), you could use `mymultiset.end()` as a marker.

(Note that this iterator does not point to the last element of a container, but to the "end", i.e. it is a special value. That's what makes it useful for flagging purposes. Be careful to only check other iterators against `mymultiset.end()`, *not* dereference it. Dereferencing `end()` or past-the-end iterators is undefined behaviour.)